# PresentScene memory : Does removeAllChildren propagate?

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a simple game with a menu scene and a game scene. When the game scene ends, it goes back to the menu scene, then to the game scene and so on.

All transitions are handled with `self.view?.presentScene(Scene(size: self.view!.bounds.size))`.

I also added this code in both the MenuScene and the GameScene :

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    self.removeAllActions()
    self.removeAllChildren()
}
```

However, using the profiling instrument "Allocations" and "Leaks", I realized that the memory consumption keeps growing (only a little though) after each `presentScene`. There is no "Leak" detection.

Does removeAllChildren propagate to all nodes within nodes ? Or should I do manual removal of all children within children ?

*Note : I am using XCode 6.1.1, iPhone Simulator iOS 8.1*

[image: Memory keeps increasing in the graph]

Comment: Memory allocated to nodes added to the scene should be automatically released when you transition to a new scene unless there is a reference to the scene or nodes.

Comment: You need not call either of the two removeAll* functions yourself. Sprite Kit will properly clean up the scene if your code got its memory management right. The fact that you're doing so is just something you did in the hope it would fix your memory problem elsewhere. Look for the actual problem, such as the scene still being strongly referenced (ie maybe you've added it to an array or singleton property) or any nodes causing retain cycles (ie sibling nodes strongly referencing each other or their parents is a sure way to create a retain cycle). Run an analyze build to get some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `deinit` to log some println() and see if does deinit, I found that MenuScene was correctly deinitializes but not GameScene.
I had to apply

```
self.removeAllActions()
self.removeAllChildren()
```

to one of the main scene node's nodes.